# Python Serwer and Android Client communication

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, android-studio, tcpclient

Hi I creating simple comminication serwer in Python 2.7, my first goal is to send "list" to android App with sockets.

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = '192.168.0.108'  # this is your localhost
PORT = 8888
list=str(["firstitem",'nextitem'])

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# socket.socket: must use to create a socket.
# socket.AF_INET: Address Format, Internet = IP Addresses.
# socket.SOCK_STREAM: two-way, connection-based byte streams.
print 'socket created'

# Bind socket to Host and Port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print 'Bind Failed, Error Code: ' + str(err[0]) + ', Message: ' + err[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket Bind Success!'

# listen(): This method sets up and start TCP listener.
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket is now listening'

while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
    #receiver
    buf = conn.recv(64)
    #sender
    send=conn.send(list)
    print buf

print 'Connect close with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
s.close()
```

And I wanna read list from python serwer then i create BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader) to receive data from python but is not going working well.

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


public class Client extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 8888;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.0.108";
    private BufferedReader input;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) throws IOException {


            try {
                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String read = input.readLine();


            Log.d("INFO", "onClick: "+read.toString());


    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas why i cant read this list?

Comment: Please post an example of how such a list would look like. Android will receive some text i suppose. Put an example text in your post please. We have no idea what you send.

Comment: And further you should tell us the errors/exceptions you have. You should tell what happens and what happens not. Otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: list is 

list=str(["firstitem",'nextitem'])

Comment: Dont show code. I asked you to tell us what is send. And i asked yet more. But you didnt react. Strange!

Comment: python serwer only send two strings.

Comment: That is not an example as i asked for. And i still asked more.